# Why LSI returns LastEvalutedKey on last record?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to implement pagination ( forward and backward) in dynamodb using LSI.

i have created LSI on abc attribute which is of type string contains characters in the form "https://mydomain/[A-Za-z1-9-_~]"

When I try to forward paginate upon reaching the last record LastEvaluated key becomes null which is expected behavior however for reverse pagination I am getting LastEvaluatedKey. referred even docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-response-LastEvaluatedKey

How do i find what is the last page using query operation, if i want to achieve backward pagination?

my code

```
params.ScanIndexForward = false;
  response = await dynamoDb.query(paramsForQuery).promise();
  console.log('LE', response.LastEvaluatedKey);
  const arrayLength = response.Items.length;
  LastEvalSortKey = {
    pk: userId,
    originalUrl: response.Items[0].originalUrl,
  };
  if (sortBy === 'createdAt')
    LastEvalSortKey[sortBy] = response.Items[0].createdAt;
  if (sortBy === 'updatedAt')
    LastEvalSortKey[sortBy] = response.Items[0].updatedAt;
  if (sortBy === 'convertedUrl')
    LastEvalSortKey[sortBy] = response.Items[0].convertedUrl;
  return {
    items: response.Items,
    nextToken: arrayLength
      ? Base64.encodeURI(JSON.stringify(LastEvalSortKey))
      : prevToken,
    prevToken: response.LastEvaluatedKey
      ? Base64.encodeURI(JSON.stringify(response.LastEvaluatedKey))
      : undefined,
  };
```

Comment: reverse pagination for me is going back to previous page for example max_results = 2 this will give me first 2 pages, the response will give next token ( used as exclusive start key), response for this will give next toke and previous token, using previous token i can go to first page. this is what i have achieved, there is no need to go through all pages

Comment: twitter is also doing the same i guess but instead they are using single token in the response, since i am using serverless i cannot maintain previous state that is why i need to send 2 tokens

Comment: Then I do not understand the question. If you already know how to get a previous token (which I would not know how to get) then what is there left to do? What does twitter have to do with anything, do they use straight dynamodb access for their pagination as well?

Comment: twitter is just an example or motivation for me to implement pagination it has no direct relation with this question, but i know how to get a previous token, my problem is when there i have reached on last record during reverse pagination i shoudl not recive LastEvaluatedKey but here in my case i am reciveing it which is odd

Comment: i updated my question with code, for better understanding.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation you linked to has the answer:

> If LastEvaluatedKey is not empty, **it does not necessarily mean that there is more data in the result set.** The only way to know when you have reached the end of the result set is when LastEvaluatedKey is empty.

The only way you can know that you've reached the end is to query until you get an empty `LastEvaluatedKey`.

If you can guarantee that the size of the data in a single page won't come close to the 1 MB query limit, one trick you can use is to query for (page + 1) items.

If the query returns `page + 1` items, you can throw away the last item and use it to know that there is another page. If it returns less items and you have a `LastEvaluatedKey`, you can either assume that there is no additional data, or perform an additional single item query to check whether you're at the end.